# Update an entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a generic repository class

```
 public class Repository<T>
    where T : class
{
    AccountingEntities ctx = new AccountingEntities();

    public T Add(T entity)
    {
        ctx.Set<T>().Add(entity);
        SaveChanges();
        return entity;
    }

    public T Update(T entity, int id)
    {
        T existing = ctx.Set<T>().Find(id);
        if (existing != null)
        {
            ctx.Entry(existing).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
            SaveChanges();
        }
        return existing;
    }

    public T GetSingle(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter)
    {
        var query = ctx.Set<T>().AsNoTracking().Where(filter).FirstOrDefault();
        return query;
    }

    private void SaveChanges()
    {
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

and I have two table item and bank. And every bank can have multi items.

I have two buttons add and edit and one global repository in my form.

When I open form and fill data and click add so record will save and every

thing is ok but at this time when I click edit there will be error let's see

my edit button code :

```
private void _btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var item = repository.GetSingle(i => i.Id == id);

            // here i update property of item 

            item = repository.Update(item, item.Id);
            // here i get updated item
    }
```

my problem is that at this line of code

```
var item = repository.GetSingle(i => i.Id == id);
```

when i get item, it's navigation property (here bank entity) is filled

but at this line of code

```
item = repository.Update(item, item.Id);
```

When I update item and get it, it's navigation property (bank) is null

and I can't use item. Bank because it's null.

Finally I understood where is problem I created global repository

```
Repository<Item> repository = new Repository<Item>();
```

and use repository in add and edit method. And when I created

separate repository in each add and edit method it works fine

I want to know why this happen?

Comment: Why are you using `item = repository.Update(item, itemId);` ? you are assigning something to the object `item` in this line? I believe you just need to do `repository.Update(item, itemId);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use eager loading using `Include()` , but first edit `GetSingle()`. EF has turned on by default lazy loading. So you need do it  like this:

```
 public virtual T GetSingle(Func<T, bool> where,
         params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navigationProperties)
    {
        T item = null;
        using (var context = new MainContext())
        {
            IQueryable<T> dbQuery = context.Set<T>();

            //Apply eager loading
            foreach (Expression<Func<T, object>> navigationProperty in navigationProperties)
                dbQuery = dbQuery.Include<T, object>(navigationProperty);

            item = dbQuery
                .AsNoTracking() //Don't track any changes for the selected item
                .FirstOrDefault(where); //Apply where clause
        }
        return item;
    }
```

Now you can load `Bank` entity

```
var item = repository.GetSingle(i => i.Id == id).Include(b=>b.Bank);
```

Here you find [more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: my getsingle method load bank entity but after  this item = repository.ite.... bank will be null

Comment: Using this edit will be load also when you call select.